# Delete complete folder using a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I am using the following expression to delete a folder from PowerShell. I need to delete a complete folder (including all the files and sub folders).

```
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $DesFolder
```

But this gives me the exception **"The directory is not empty"**

I am not getting this exception every time when I run the program; it happens randomly. What would be the reason for this and how do I fix this? Because I was failing to reproduce this.

Comment: are there files in those folders? perhaps you need to delete them too using a similar command or to instruct your current command to do so

Comment: @Valamas-AUS-  yes. there are files and folders inside it

Answer (score 0):

We cannot delete an non-empty directory using commands like rmdir or Remove-Item, this is to avoid accidental deletion of important system files by users during programming.

Therefore before trying to delete the directory, empty it. Clear the contents and then delete it. :)

Comment: It confusing. First you say **We cannot delete an empty directory**. Then you say **Therefore before trying to delete the directory, empty it**. I cannot understand. confused.

Comment: I am sorry..i will edit the post..i meant "We cannot delete an non-empty directory"

Answer (score 0):

`Remove-Item -Recurse` always deletes the directory and all its contents recursively. But it may still fail if directory is modified (i.e. new files are created) by some third-party activity in middle of remove process.

Also, if some of the files cannot be deleted (e.g. due to permission restrictions) `Remove-Item` will also fail.

So, I'd recommend you to check what exactly is laying inside the directory after exception.

Comment: This is a one chunk of a larger process. If it fails, it goes up to 3 tries. once I analyze the logs I figured out if it fail in one attempt, in the next attempt it won't happen(deletion). I cannot reproduce this failure. I want to figured out why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell throws this error when there's a file still currently locked under operation by some other program. I would suggest looking at your script and investigating at which command the operation could take non-standard time, and right after that adding a `Start-Sleep -Seconds 10` which would ask the script process to sleep for 10 seconds, which is plenty of time for a lot of I/O dependent processes to gracefully exit and clean themselves up.

I generally have had issues with Maven causing the above issue, and I modified my script like below extract:

```
...
# wait for dependent processes to exit
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
# remove directory
Remove-Item $MyDir -Recurse -Force
...
```