# PowerShell command to delete a directory containing large redundant folders

Tags: powershell

Is there a PowerShell command to delete a directory containing large redundant folders?

1-2 TB are in each folder. How would I write this? Doing it via [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer) is too slow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18245795 should give you a place to start. If it doesn't work, you can post your code here, explain how it's not working for you, and ask a more specific question, and we'll try and help. We're not really a code writing service, where you post your requirements and we churn out code to meet them. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To remove folder you can use [Remove-Item](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849765.aspx) cmdlet

```
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $pathToDelete
```

The command above will delete $pathToDelete with all its contents.

If you want to delete only items which meet certain conditions, e.g. files greater than 1 GB contained in the current directory, you can write something like:

```
Get-Childitem . -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.length -gt 1gb } | Foreach ($_) { Remove-Item $_.FullName }
```